# Use solve_ivp's 'events' to check for convergence

Tags: python, events, scipy, ode

## Problem:

Assume a simple decay process as described by the following ode:

```
def exponential_decay(t,y):
    return -0.5 * y
```

This can easily be integrated with the help of scipy's *solve_ivp()*

```
t_min = 0; t_max = 25; y0 = 1
sol = solve_ivp(exponential_decay, [t_min, t_max],[y0],dense_output=True)
```

The resulting solution might look like this:

[image]

## Question:

I would like to use solve_ivp's "event"-finder to check for convergence to reduce the computational time spent after convergence is reached.
However, the designed signature of the event tracker when an event function is provided is:

```
event(t,y) -> t_event
```

An event occurs when the return of the event function is equal to zero.

Because *event(t,y)* only knows the current y(t) it can not be used straightforwardly to implement standard convergence criteria as they all require a series of y.

So to cut this short: **Is there a good way to do so, to use the event finder to check for convergence?**
Or to make use of any kind of range of y(t) in the convergence tracker?
This seems like something that would be helpful in many applications

A (bad way) to do so I found is to pass a global variable in and out of event(t,y) that stores the the differnt (t,y(t). However, this is not only extreamly unelegant, it also offsets the computational efficiency provided by *solive_ivp()*

Comment: You can just use an implicit solver like `method="Radau"`, then the flat end of the solution gets very large internal step sizes, significantly reducing the computational effort after convergence is reached. Playing with the absolute (tight) and relative (larger) tolerances while using the explicit solvers might also give such a behavior, but is not as straight-forward.

Comment: In the solve_ivp implementation that comes not out as drastically as expected from Hairer/Wanner "Solving ODE II", but still the step size increases on the flat end in all situations. Set `t_max=50` to see it more clearly, add a line `plot(sol.t, sol.y[0], 'rx')` to see the internal steps in the plot. The expectation that failed to materialize was that in the explicit methods the step size reaches a maximum while in the implicit methods it steadily increases.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I will give it a shot.
Nevertheless, it does not answer my original question.
In my application I also need to know the point of convergence.
(I am aware that I can simply calculate it after the time integration.
Because the time integration is in a inner loop i would like to save that computational time)
It seems odd to me that a well developed solver like solve_ivp does not offer this functionality. Is there a specific reason why this is hard or not implemented?

Comment: It is not really well-developed. It is more a proof-of concept implementation, a slow solver for small problems, to have a minimal functionality, events and dense output, that is expected from a modern solver package. And the interface for events in Matlab is better suited for large applications. If you want usefulness, turn to the julia-lang package differentialequations.jl, where efficiency for large-scale problems was better taken into account.

Comment: If there is a limit, you could make an event for the norm of the derivative or its logarithm falling below some threshold. Then use the last point as initial guess for a non-linear solver to find the solution for zero derivatives. In more general situations the equilibrium position will move slowly in time, generating an asymptotic curve. This will be much harder to detect without problem-specific knowledge.

Comment: I feel like I am missing something. Lets assume for this comment that:  
there exists a limit (but we don't know what it is).
1) how can I calculate the derivative of the function if all i know (due to the event-function-signature) is the current t, and y(t)?
2) for the logarithm approach to work I would need to know the limit, don't I? You mean something like ( log(y(t)-y(t_limit) ) goes to -inf for t going to t_limit i presume? Hence, i can set a epsilon that's "good enough".
Please correct me if I am wrong, I would love to be wrong.
(Sadly, I am committed to python at this point)

Comment: You get the derivative from your derivative function. Yes, to work with the value directly you would have to know what the limit is, you could get the list of stationary points via a non-linear solver applied to the derivatives function (and a large collection of random initial guesses). Make an event for every stationary point...